# CSS props brought in by the Vuetify framework being duplicated according to browser console

Tags: css, npm, sass, vuetify.js, package.json

I have an app which uses the Vuetify framework and Laravel.

Here is what the **app.blade.php** where all vue pages are based to show all of the external stylesheets used. All vue pages are seeing duplicated styles:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" class="prevent-horizontal-scroll">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- External stylesheets -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
#app {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <sidebar-background>
            @yield('content')
        </sidebar-background>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" ></script>
</html>
```

Example of a blade template which shows the settings page of the app called settings.blade.php based on app.blade.php:

```
@extends('app')

@section('title', 'Settings')

@section('content')
    <div id="app">
        <settings-tabs/>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Here is my package.json file to show the versions of all packages and display whether there could be a mismatch between the versions:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "mix",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "production": "mix --production",
        "prod": "mix --production",
        "cypress:open": "cypress open",
        "postinstall": "patch-package"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@mdi/font": "^5.9.55",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.1",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
        "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.11.1",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.11.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.24",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
        "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass": "~1.32.13",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "webpack": "^5.40.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^25.3.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.14.5",
        "@cypress/vue": "^2.2.3",
        "@tiptap/core": "^2.0.0-beta.85",
        "@tiptap/extension-document": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
        "@tiptap/extension-mention": "^2.0.0-beta.61",
        "@tiptap/extension-paragraph": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
        "@tiptap/extension-text": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
        "@tiptap/vue-2": "^2.0.0-beta.39",
        "ag-charts-community": "^3.3.0",
        "ag-charts-vue": "^3.3.0",
        "ag-grid-community": "^25.3.0",
        "ag-grid-enterprise": "^25.3.0",
        "ag-grid-vue": "^25.3.0",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "cypress": "^7.6.0",
        "interactjs": "^1.10.11",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.0",
        "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
        "tippy.js": "^6.3.1",
        "tiptap-commands": "^1.17.1",
        "tiptap-extensions": "^1.35.2",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-class-component": "^7.2.6",
        "vue-easy-dnd": "^1.10.2",
        "vue-property-decorator": "^8.0.0",
        "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
        "vuetify": "^2.5.5",
        "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.2",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2",
        "yargs": "^17.0.1",
        "yargs-parser": "^20.2.9"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                {
                    "targets": {
                        "esmodules": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
        ]
    }
}
```

The Vuetify styles are being duplicated (here is what it looks like in the console of any page in the app):

[image]

I'm unsure of why they're being duplicated and also where the  tag styles are coming from. It doesn't quite make sense to me why also the vuetify.min.css styles are being crossed out. Would you know what might be causing the duplicated styles based on the info above?